# How to fix Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'datatables.net' on Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I want to bundle the vendor dependencies of my website using webpack, but I'm having a problem with jquery dependant dependencies. The only thing I need is to bundle the files into one, and import it on my index.html. It seems to me that webpack is trying to import things from the library, which is not necessary, the final bundle is the goal.

```
ERROR in ./plataforma/assets/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'datatables.net' in '/Users/julianograms/Documents/Mapi/mapi-front/plataforma/assets/js'
 @ ./plataforma/assets/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js 5:62-145
 @ ./plataforma/src/vendor.js
```